# Conditionally install from requirements.txt depending on the Python Implementation

Tags: python

I have a requirements.txt file that specifies an optional dependency that fails when running on PYPY.

I know you can make lines in the requirements.txt file conditional on Python version, or operating system. For instance:

Following dependencies will only be installed for Python 3.5+ and on Win32 respectively

```
black;python_version > '3.5' 
colorama;platform_system=="Windows"
```

However, I'm looking for a way to only install a package if the `platform.python_implementation()` is CPython, or not PYPY.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I was writing this, I found the answer:

https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0508/

The previous code can be augmented as follows:

```
black;python_version > '3.5' and platform_python_implementation=="CPython"
colorama;platform_system=="Windows"
```